# Misaligned text within div in different browsers

Tags: css

For some reason I cannot get the placement of a line of text to remain consistent in different browsers. I'm trying to get the comments line and the "like" heart line to align correctly like you see in the lower right of this image taken from Firefox:

[image]

However, when viewing the same page in chrome or Safari it looks like this:

[image]

I tried messing around with the relative positioning of the div in CSS but haven't been able to find a solution for this problem. Any help would be much appreciated! The website is www.misscarispreschool.com if you'd like to check it out.

Thank you!

Comment: you should provide CSS applied as well.

Comment: Thanks ssilas777. Because of the amount of CSS applied I figured it would be easier for both parties to just check it out in Firebug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `.entry-meta-right` class needs a width of at least `112px`, but you may want to make it bigger than that, depending on what your going for.

Also, `.like-74 .like, .action_like { margin-top: 2px; }` makes it look nice
 : )

Comment: You are a genius. I'm not sure why I didn't think about setting the width. I guess I figured it would do it correctly for me automatically. Regarding the .like-74 .like, .action_like { margin-top: 2px; }, I assume that is meant to align the comments and "like" section so that they are are even. I tried it and it doesn't seem to work for me. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I got it to work by adding a 2px top margin to div id="watch-action". Thank you so much for your help!